# Service function undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am tryin the following code

In my services.js one of the services is

```
 .service('AppService', ['$http', 'AuthService', function ($http, AuthService) {

  var getUserData = function(){
  return {
    "fname": "Admin",
    "lname": "ladmin",
    "array" : [{}, {}]
   }
}
return {
  getUserData: getUserData
}
}]);
```

In my controller, I have

```
  AppService.getUserData().then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
})
```

Error : `AppService.getUserData(...).then is not a function`

I have the service injected. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just remove this statement `this.getUserData = function(){`

Comment: You entertain `then` thing you need to `return Promise` see more here [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating the `then` function in your call `AppService.getUserData().then(function(response){`, which implies your service should return a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (but that's not your case).

To make your code work, remove the then function:

```
var data = AppService.getUserData(); //no promise used, your actual situation.
```

if you want to use a promise, leave your controller function as it is and modify your service like so:

```
.service('AppService', ['$http', 'AuthService', '$q', function ($http, AuthService, $q) {

    getUserData : function(){
       return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          resolve({
               "fname": "Admin",
               "lname": "ladmin",
               "array" : [{}, {}]
           });
       }
    }       
}]);
```

this way, you'll use a promise (but in your example you don't need it, it's a simple call with a return)

Comment: I was exactly tweaking through $q injection earlier and was just doing some weird $q.resolve stuff to make things happen. Many Thanks !

Comment: I intend to use the promise from service in router's resolve. How can I do this. I tried to do thenable like `AppService.getUserdata().then(function(response){ return response })` but to no use.

Comment: Try to share your code in a new question, so we can better see what's your issue (it's free! :) )